Postgis upgrade from 3.1.11 to 3.2.7 or 3.3.6 or any higher version fails with an error extension "postgis" has no update path
Current Database version: Postgres 13
Target Database version: Postgres 14/15 via pg_upgrade
Current postgis version: 3.1.11
Target postgis version: 3.2.7 or 3.3.4
Steps performed:

Upgrade database and then upgrade postgis:


Database was upgraded to postgres 14 with original postgis version postgis31_14
postgis version before ugprade:

postgres=# select postgis_full_version();
POSTGIS="3.1.11 ca03d62" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="130" (procs need upgrade for use with PostgreSQL "140") GEOS="3.12.1-CAPI-1.18.1" SFCGAL="1.4.1" PROJ="9.4.0 (1 row)

Postgis was upgraded to reflect new database version
`SELECT PostGIS_Extensions_Upgrade();
NOTICE:  Updating extension postgis 3.1.11
NOTICE:  Extension postgis_raster is not available or not packagable for some reason
NOTICE:  Extension postgis_tiger_geocoder is not available or not packagable for some reason
postgis_extensions_upgrade


Upgrade completed, run SELECT postgis_full_version(); for details
(1 row)`
`select postgis_full_version();
POSTGIS="3.1.11 ca03d62" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="140" GEOS="3.12.1-CAPI-1.18.1" SFCGAL="1.4.1" PROJ="9.4.0" LIBXML="2.9.13" LIBJSON="0.14" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3
(1 row)`

After this a new version of postgis32_14 (3.2.7) was installed after removing the old version 3.1.11 (I noticed that dnf does not allow both versions due to conflict with some files that already exist. Error details below).

Once downloaded when I check postgis version on DB it shows below message:
POSTGIS="3.2.7 32dc0cc" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="140" GEOS="3.12.1-CAPI-1.18.1" SFCGAL="1.4.1" PROJ="9.4.0" LIBXML="2.9.13" LIBJSON="0.14" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3" rade) (sfcgal procs from "3.1.11 ca03d62" need upgrade)

On executing SELECT PostGIS_Extensions_Upgrade(); it throws below error:
NOTICE:  Updating extension postgis from 3.1.11 to 3.2.7 ERROR:  extension "postgis" has no update path from version "3.1.11" to version "3.2.7" CONTEXT:  SQL statement "ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE TO "3.2.7";" PL/pgSQL function postgis_extensions_upgrade() line 82 at EXECUTE



Upgrade postgis and then upgrade postgres


Postgis version 32_13 (3.2.7) or 33_13 (3.3.6) was downloaded by removing 31_13 (3.1.11) but on Upgrade, error messages is same as in first case.

After downloading new postgis version, I am able to see that default version is the new one and installed version is old one but by no means I am able to upgrade it. I tried even via ALTER EXTENSION POSTGIS UPDATE but without success.
To install fresh db with latest postgis version and perform pg dump (Hard Upgrade) is not possible for me due to DB size being greater than 1TB.
While upgrading postgis in past from 2.5 to 3.0, link solution used to work but between 3.1 and 3.2 or 3.3 linking .so file does not work, it throws an error as below:
could not load library "$libdir/postgis_raster-3": ERROR:  incompatible library "/usr/pgsql-14/lib/postgis_raster-3.so": version mismatch DETAIL:  Server is version 14, library is version 13.
Error encountered while downloading new version of postgis alongside of old version:
Error: Transaction test error: file /usr/pgsql-14/lib/address_standardizer-3.so from install of postgis32_14-3.2.7-3PGDG.rhel9.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgis31_14-3. file /usr/pgsql-14/lib/postgis-3.so from install of postgis32_14-3.2.7-3PGDG.rhel9.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgis31_14-3.1.11-3PGDG.rh file /usr/pgsql-14/lib/postgis_raster-3.so from install of postgis32_14-3.2.7-3PGDG.rhel9.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgis31_14-3.1.11-3 file /usr/pgsql-14/lib/postgis_sfcgal-3.so from install of postgis32_14-3.2.7-3PGDG.rhel9.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgis31_14-3.1.11-3 file /usr/pgsql-14/lib/postgis_topology-3.so from install of postgis32_14-3.2.7-3PGDG.rhel9.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgis31_14-3.1.11 file /usr/pgsql-14/share/extension/address_standardizer.control from install of postgis32_14-3.2.7-3PGDG.rhel9.x86_64 conflicts with file from package file /usr/pgsql-14/share/extension/address_standardizer_data_us.control from install of postgis32_14-3.2.7-3PGDG.rhel9.x86_64 conflicts with file from file /usr/pgsql-14/share/extension/postgis.control from install of postgis32_14-3.2.7-3PGDG.rhel9.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgis31_14- file /usr/pgsql-14/share/extension/postgis_raster.control from install of postgis32_14-3.2.7-3PGDG.rhel9.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgi file /usr/pgsql-14/share/extension/postgis_sfcgal.control from install of postgis32_14-3.2.7-3PGDG.rhel9.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgi file /usr/pgsql-14/share/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder.control from install of postgis32_14-3.2.7-3PGDG.rhel9.x86_64 conflicts with file from packag file /usr/pgsql-14/share/extension/postgis_topology.control from install of postgis32_14-3.2.7-3PGDG.rhel9.x86_64 conflicts with file from package post
If anybody experienced similar issue and found the solution or any help from postgis experts would be helpful.
I did not try dropping extension (tried only for raster) but I believe we cannot drop extension and re-create as it might corrupt old functions or data already available on DB.
Tried all possible solution found on Stack Overflow or on other portals but unfortunately nothing helped. I would be grateful to the person who could provide me possible workaround to solve this issue.

Just an update: DB was migrated from Centos7 to Rocky9 and the issue occurred on Rocky9. Could it be related to compilation of binaries on different os?

did you ever find a solution? I'm struggling with the same "No update path" error while going from 3.2.7 to 3.3.6

I'm running postgresql 12 on a Centos Stream 9 machine and I was trying to upgrade from postgis 3.2.7 to either 3.3 or 3.4 but in both cases I would hit a similar "No update path" error.
After some investigation it looks like the update paths are defined by SQL files found here:
/usr/pgsql-12/share/extension

I had upgrade paths all the way up to 3.2.6 but there was no script for 3.2.7. I'm assuming it was missing just due to a packaging issue. Since all of the scripts are just symlinks to the common files, I was able to create the necessary ones for 3.2.7:
cd /usr/pgsql-12/share/extension
ln -s postgis--TEMPLATED--TO--ANY.sql postgis--3.2.7--ANY.sql
ln -s postgis_raster--TEMPLATED--TO--ANY.sql postgis_raster--3.2.7--ANY.sql
ln -s postgis_sfcgal--TEMPLATED--TO--ANY.sql postgis_sfcgal--3.2.7--ANY.sql
ln -s postgis_topology--TEMPLATED--TO--ANY.sql postgis_topology--3.2.7--ANY.sql

Running select postgis_extensions_upgrade() was then successful.

Dear mbosecke, your suggestion was perfect. Thank you for the wonderful workaround.
